# How to execute mysql query without changing the position on page

Tags: php

My php pages are long and dynamic. So when user is at very bottom of the page, i want to execute query without changing the current position of the user at page. I have been trying to use jquery but that too is reloading page. How can i do that. Its preferable to execute query on anchor.

Comment: I see. So it's like a unlimited scroll, like [this](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/demos/jquery/infinite_scroll.php)?

Comment: `an` unlimited. You will need to use ajax and a connector for PHP. The php aspect should send new data only, and the ajax receives and appends it on to the page.